# Compiling my own python has broken system scripts?

Tags: debian, python, package-management, dependencies, crunchbang

(For those not familiar with it, CrunchBang is basically a preconfigured Debian Squeeze.)

So a while back, I was writing a script and wanted to use a Python feature introduced in 2.7. Since the latest version I could get from Debian Squeeze's apt repo is 2.6.6.8, I decided to download the latest source and build it myself. After wrangling dependencies myself, I finally got something working, and finished my project.

However, since then, a number of system scripts have stopped working. I noticed that they (the now broken scripts) all start with `#!/usr/bin/env python`[1] and depend on one or more things that have been installed by apt-get/synaptic, but are associated with Python 2.6. A few I've fixed by manually changing the header to `#!/usr/bin/python`, but now I'm starting to wonder

1. Is this normal for people that roll their own Python?
2. Did I compile/set up 2.7 wrong somehow?
3. Is it unreasonable to expect packages installed with apt-get/synaptic to 'lock in' with the version of dependencies they were installed with?
4. Should I somehow reconfcd /igure my $PATH so that the `/usr` file is found before the `/usr/local` file?
5. Should I just delete the hardlink file /usr/local/bin/python and have all of my scripts start with `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7`?
6. Do I have to manually install all of the missing libraries, etc. for `/usr/local`? If so, what's the best way to do this?
7. Should I file bugs with the package maintainers, projects themselves, or both?

[1] Which, because of how my path is set up, invokes my `/usr/local/bin/python` (2.7) rather than the system's `/usr/bin/python` (2.6)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal enough that most people who build their own Python environments use something like [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) to manage them.  Replacing the system-provided Perl, Python, or Ruby is almost never a good idea, and all three languages provide ways for developers to manage their own private installations (for Perl there is PerlBrew and for Ruby there's RVM).

Comment: That's awesome! I heard of virtualenv in the context of deployment, didn't realize it was useful for development, too. I'm guessing I don't want to use apt-get for this, either? So then I should delete `/usr/local/binmkvir/python`, `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 dev` and then `workon X`/`deactivate`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (`/usr/local/binmkvir/python` looks slightly confused), but `apt-get install virtualenv` is fine.  You *do* want to remove, or at least relocate, the `python` executable you had built and use `virtualenv` to install it properly so that you can use it without interfering with the system Python; see the `virtualenv` documentation.

Comment: Whoops, by `/usr/local/binmkvir/python` I meant `/usr/local/bin/python`. Of course it's just my luck that I need v1.5.1+ to use Python 2.7, and the latest apt will give me is 1.4.9. I guess I have a ways to go. (and I must be blind, because I still don't see where in the docs it says to rm other pythons. The closest I see is Python's README saying to altinstall all but the primary version)

Comment: It doesn't say that explicitly; it's implied by the fact that overriding the system-provided Perl/Python/Ruby is almost certain to break things (as indeed it did for you).  "caution:  fire is hot"

Comment: So then why is the advice almost invariably to `make install` rather than `make altinstall`? It's like saying "put your computer in the fire"

Comment: That I couldn't tell you, aside from the assumption being that you're doing an initial install (which is the default assummpion even though it's usually wrong for shells and fundamental scripting languages).